# Mongoose populate returns empty array but returns data without populate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to fetch appointments and populate them with user details and doctor details. I have a schema like this

```
let appointmentSchema = new Schema({
  reason: String,
  start: DateType,
  end: DateType,
  appointmentStamp: Number,
  userId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  doctorId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Doctor'
  },
  approved: Boolean,
  held: Boolean,
  timeOfAcceptance: Number,
  createdOn: { type: Number, default: (new Date().getTime()) },
  updatedAt: Mixed
}, {runSettersOnQuery: true})
```

And on running

```
Appointment.find({userId: authId}).populate('userId doctorId').exec()
```

I get an empty array
but 
Appointment.find({userId: authId}).exec()
return all the appointments for that user with the userId supplied in find
what am I missing out

Here is a sample appointment

```
  {
    "_id": "5a0d424079191657fca9e853",
    "reason": "Say Hello",
    "approved": false,
    "held": false,
    "doctor": "5a0add9b577d7916187cd9f2",
    "patient": "59f5df20a3071554c5f843e1",
    "appointmentStamp": 1510927380000,
    "__v": 0,
    "createdOn": 1510817910134
  }
```

Comment: If you receive an empty result, what that usually means is that the referencing `ObjectId` values do not actually match anything in the related collections. Show a sample appointment and the `User` and `Doctor` entries you believe should match it, but are not returning.

Comment: Yeah okay that's the appointment. Now also show the `Doctor` and `User` which are supposed to match the `ObjectId` values present in this document. What you are being told is that documents with those values present in their `_id` fields do not exist. Also check the collection names. Mongoose is expecting these to be called `"doctors"` and `"users"` respectively. In brief you should be able to do `Doctor.findById("5a0add08577d7916187cd9f1")` and if you cannot get a result, then this indicates a problem with your data.

Comment: I am getting a result for Doctor.findById('5a0add08577d7916187cd9f1')

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked, don't know why

```
patient: {
   type: String,
   ref: 'patient'
},
doctor: {
   type: String,
   ref: 'doctor'
}
```

instead of ObjectId I used type of String
then the query be like

```
Appointment.find({patient: authId, canceled: false})
  .populate('patient doctor').exec()
```